# Remove UNIQUE from column using yii2 migrations

Tags: php, sql, migration, yii2

I have a column that is unique, how do I remove the UNIQUE key from that column using migrations.

I am using the latest version of yii 2

```
public function up()
{
    $this->alterColumn('user', 'email', $this->string(255)->notNull());

}

public function down()
{
    $this->alterColumn('user', 'email', $this->string(255)->notNull()->unique());
}
```

Altering the column as such doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the sql to create a Unique index is something like this

```
//sql to add a unqique index
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD UNIQUE (
`email`
);

//sql to remove a unqique index
ALTER TABLE 'user' DROP INDEX email;
```

just use [dropIndex()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-migration.html#dropIndex%28%29-detail) and remove the unique index.

I just tested it with the `username` column on my `user` table  because i didn't had a `email`column and it worked as expected. In my case the username column was unique therefore migration/up removed the index and down adds the index again.

```
public function up()
{
    // remove the unique index
    $this->dropIndex('username', 'user');
}

public function down()
{
    // add the unique index again
    $this->createIndex('username', 'user', 'username', $unique = true );
}
```

Comment: $this->dropIndex('email', 'user'); 

Doesn't remove it :(

Comment: in my opinion it should. have you looked into your database stucture that your unique index for the email column has the name `email` ?

Comment: tested it and i worked as expected. I have updated the answer with working code.

Comment: For postgres if you get on drop index an exception cannot drop because constraint requires it, change `$this->dropIndex(...)` to `$this->dropForeignKey(...)`